# How to run multiple ignite clusters on same network

Tags: ignite

I have several machines on my intranet. If I switch on ignite on two of them, they automatically discover each other and become part of a single cluster. If I start ignite on a third machine, it automatically connects to the cluster.

How can I prevent this.

Basically, I want to run two clusters of Ignite on a single network. I have two testing environments, I want separate Ignites for both these environments.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you're using `TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder` in `TcpDiscoverySpi` configuration.
It's possible to archive network isolation, but you should use `TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder` instead of `TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder`. The example of configuration could be found here https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/tcpip-discovery#section-static-ip-finder.

Comment: The documentation says:

You are only required to provide at least one IP address of a remote node, but usually it is advisable to provide 2 or 3 addresses of grid nodes that you plan to start at some point of time in the future. **Once a connection to any of the provided IP addresses is established, Ignite will automatically discover all other grid nodes**.

Does the bold part above mean that it will automatically discover only those nodes which are a part of configuration.

P.S. you are right that I am using MulticastIpFinder

Comment: If I've caught your idea correctly then the answer is no, it will automatically discover all of them. This list is used for the initial connection when joining a cluster.

Comment: Does that mean, there is not solution to the problem. Would it make a difference if I use TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder instead of TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder?

Comment: As far as can see it's actually a probable solution. You can decide what hosts and ports you will use for cluster `A` and what hosts and ports for cluster `B`. To add a new node to the `A` you could just mention some of existing nodes (in `A`, not in `B`) in the new node configuration. Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks so much Vladimir. I will check this and revert with the results.